# Using head and tail in UNIX to extract specific transaction

Tags: shell, unix

I have a question regarding using the `head` and `tail` commands in UNIX to truncate a specific transaction from a huge transaction log.

```
head -X <<<filename>>> | tail -Y > <<<Truncatedfile>>>
```

where `X` is the number of lines I want from the beginning of the file and `Y` is the number of lines I want from the bottom of the file.

How can I modify this code to have the truncated file with just the transactions for a unique transaction ID? For example:-
The file contains transaction logs for `n` number of transaction IDs in a sequence. So, if I only need logs extracted for just 1 single transaction ID how to modify the above code?

Comment: Do the transaction IDs appear on each line of the file? You probably want `grep`, or perhaps `sed`.

Comment: Please don't write command names with initial capital letters; `tail` and `Tail` are distinct names.

Comment: Please post a sample of the transaction log, which will help determine the best command to use to extract the line(s) you want.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't modify the above code, instead you'd

```
grep -w transactionid filename
```

<sub>Assuming that the transactionid appears as a separate word (-w)</sub>

**Edit** You can include some context lines (this includes 10 lines after the match:)

```
grep -w -A 10 transactionid filename
```

Alternatively,

```
grep -vw transactionid filename
```

Simple hides all lines **NOT** containing the transaction id. This close to equivalent to doing `sed -e '/transactionid/!d'`.

---

To print lines 5-12

```
sed -n '5,12p' filename
```

Comment: So no need to do a head and tail?

Comment: @Keith Thompson - Yes, the transaction IDs appear on pretty much all the lines.

Comment: Let me re-phrase my question. Is there a way to truncate the file from the 1st instance of the transaction ID till the last instance of the transaction ID.

Comment: Also, just to add that the transaction log is a huge huge file of like 1GB. So, the command shouldn't just hang up due to this huge file.

Comment: To select lines 'around' the tx id, use `grep -C3` (3 lines before and after), or `grep -A3` (3 lines after) and so on. This would likely have the intended effect (as it will also include the first and last matches of course)

Comment: @chepner - Sorry, can't provide a sample log file as its production log file.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that. Just that not all the lines for the transaction ID have the transaction ID on the line specifically such as - Request/Response XMLs in the log doesn't have any transaction ID. So, the command will miss those lines. What I am trying to achieve is to pick the log from the 1st instance of transaction ID till the last instance of transaction ID. That way, I wont miss anything in the truncated file.

Comment: You know, we aren't psychic so we can't "guess" about the existance of "Request/Response XMLs" in the log. Anyways, `grep -A3` or `grep -C3`  (you can try higher values if there's more lines in-between matches) would work